# How to get the required tag from the below xml using xpath in Azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

```
<DeviceProfile xmlns="http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/">
    <Metadata>
        <DeviceProfileType>xwu</DeviceProfileType>
        <OntologyReference xmlns:tns="http://www.yyy.com/schema/m2m/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
        <AssetParams ParamName="Device-ID" DisplayName="Device-ID" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="true" DataType="String" Category="IoT" LiveUpdate="false" xpath="'Unit-ID''" Decoding="none" MinLength="1" />
        <AssetParams ParamName="deviceHost" DisplayName="Device Host" Mandatory="false" ReadOnly="false" DataType="String" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
        <AssetParams ParamName="devicePort" DisplayName="Device Port" Mandatory="false" ReadOnly="false" DataType="number" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
        <AssetParams ParamName="deviceMSISDN" DisplayName="Device MSISDN" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="false" DataType="number" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" />
        <AssetParams ParamName="preferredProtocol" DisplayName="Preferred Protocol" Mandatory="true" ReadOnly="false" DataType="Choice" Category="IoT" Decoding="none" ChoiceElements="TCP,UDP" />
    </Metadata> 
</DeviceProfile>
```

In the above xml how to get all AssetParams tag using xpath in Azure logic apps.

Comment: **Very important question:** What are  you going to do with them?  It matters enough to change the answer completely.

Comment: convert to json of only assetparam tag

Comment: It would likely be easier to convert the whole thing to JSON first, then extract what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH is:

```
@xpath(xml(body('Get_blob_content_using_path')), 'string(/*[local-name()=\"DeviceProfile\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/\"]/*[local-name()=\"Metadata\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/\"]/*[local-name()=\"AssetParams\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://www.hp.com/schema/m2m/\"])')
```

You have to modify body('Get_blob_content_using_path') with the trigger or connector where you get that XML.